# Remove Google Test boiler framework output using command line flags

Tags: c++, googletest

So I have a Google Test that spits out output which I need. However, I do not want to include the Google Test output itself to achieve the following:

**Before**

```
Note: Google Test filter = MyTest.DISABLED_test1
...
<....OUTPUT FROM TEST....> 
...
[       OK ] MyTest.DISABLED_test1
[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran.
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

**After**

```
...
<....OUTPUT FROM TEST....> 
...
```

**Question:**

I am using command line arguments to run a DISABLED test and I was wondering if there is a way to disable the test's boiler plate output generated from the framework itself using a command line flag? I wanna keep the other tests unchanged and I cannot change any of the framework's config files.

Comment: Google Test doesn't have a command-line option to modify the beyond using XML and directing it to a file or folder. I would use `grep -v '^\['` to omit lines beginning with `[`.

Answer (score 1):

You should add command line parameter and parse it by yourself in the main(). 
When parameter exist, you can call gtest to remove the default event listener (the one that prints the results) and you will have silent gtest:

```
if(silent_run) {
  auto& listeners = ::testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()->listeners();
  delete listeners.Release(listeners.default_result_printer());
}
```

Note, the code above should be executed before RUN_ALL_TESTS().